# Python: Excel won't open file even with \\

Tags: python, excel, path, directory, win32com

I was having the error:

```
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', ...
```

Then after some searching I figured out the problem was with /, which are not accepted by com32. In the end I was able to change the / with \\, but the error is still there. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
def WriteValues():
    global ws
    global ws2
    global wb
    global wb2
    global filename

    Row = 2
    MaxRow = 9000
    while Row < MaxRow:
        if ws["A" + str(Row)] != "":
            Copy = copyRange(1,Row,1000,Row,ws)
            Paste = pasteRange(1,2,1000,2,ws2,Copy)
            Email = ws["C" + str(Row)]
            wb2.save(filename)
            wb2.close()
            office = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
            office.Application.Quit()
            office = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
            print filename
            filename2 = str(os.path.normpath(filename))
            filename2 = (filename2.encode('string-escape'))
            print filename2
            wb2 = office.Workbooks.Open(filename2)
            wb2.RefreshAll()
            wb2.Save()
            wb2.Close()
            Print()
            SendEmail(Needs[0],Needs[1],Needs[2],Needs[3],Needs[4],Email)
            Row = Row + 1
```

Output:

```
=============== RESTART: C:\Users\macha\Desktop\Excel\Code.py ===============
C:/Users/macha/Desktop/Excel/RelatorioDeDesempenho.xlsx
C:\\Users\\macha\\Desktop\\Excel\\RelatorioDeDesempenho.xlsx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\macha\Desktop\Excel\Code.py", line 428, in <module>
    WriteValues()
  File "C:\Users\macha\Desktop\Excel\Code.py", line 418, in WriteValues
    wb2 = office.Workbooks.Open(filename2)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\Workbooks.py", line 78, in Open
    , Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Excel', u'O m\xe9todo Open da classe Workbooks falhou', u'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

PS: My computer is in Portuguese...

Comment: Did you try opening the file directly in Excel instead of through Python?

Comment: @ashleedawg Opened normally, however I tried with another file and worked properly. Thanks!!!